# Duplicate @import rules

Tags: css, duplicates

I have the situation where I get to @import the same CSS twice. Is there a way have something like a PHP require_once() in CSS? I found no answer to this so probably not :)

Scenario: The global CSS @imports some fonts and other resources. However, there is some dynamically generated content that may not appear on pages linking the global CSS and, therefore, has it's own linked CSS that happens to @import some of the same resources as the global style sheet.

When this dinamically generated content is being ouput into one of the regular CMS pages I end up linking both style sheets above and stuff like FontAwesome, for example,gets @imported twice.